# kubectl diff does not show manual changes

Tags: kubernetes, diff, kubectl

I created the following simple `deploy.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test
          image: alpine
          command: [ "sleep", "infinity" ]
          env:
            - name: TEST1
              value: VALUE1
```

I applied it to my cluster: `kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml`.

Then I edited this resource using `kubectl edit deploy test` and added new env `TEST2=VALUE2`.

Now I expect `kubectl diff -f deploy.yaml` to show the difference between server version and my local deployment descriptor, however it just does not show any changes.

How do I invoke `kubectl diff` to show changes between server version and local yaml? I want to find changes someone did and incorporate them into deployment descriptors.

I can extract server object using `kubectl get -o yaml deployment test`, remove all server-generated fields and compare it manually, however that's not very handy for large number of files and I expected `kubectl diff` to do that for me.